# Using Tagging and Autopopulate with Flask

Tags: python, flask, jquery-select2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to wrap my head around how to use a tagging system with Flask and WTForms.

Basically I have a list of keywords.  These keywords have a hierarchy (example: I **select Chicago.  Illinois and USA get automatically added** as additional keywords).

So I'm trying to find a way for users to type into an **autopopulating list**.  This form then produces the keywords and brings it back into flask, where each keyword is **used as it's own variable.**

With WTForms we need the "id" to bring back into Flask, but in a form like taggle.js or select2 **how can we separate each tag into it's own id?**  Or are there better ways to go about this?
[image: autocomplete form]

Flask

```
class ReusableForm(Form): 
    example4 = StringField('example4')

@app.route("/editor", methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def hello():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)
if request.method == 'POST':
    example4 = request.form['example4']

    if form.validate():
    # Return and do something with each keyword
    # tag1 = 'Alaska'
    # tag2 = 'Hawaii'
    # tag3 = 'California'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a dynamic form that will accept a variable number of tags being POSTed to Flask.

`forms.py`:

```
class TagForm(NoCsrfForm):
    tag_id = IntegerField(widget=HiddenInput(), default=0)
    tag_name = StringField(widget=HiddenInput(), [InputRequired(), Length(max=256)])

class MyDynamicForm(Form):
    some_field = StringField('Foo', [InputRequired()])
    some_other_field = TextAreaField('Bar', [InputRequired()])
    some_tags = FieldList(FormField(TagForm))
```

`views.py`:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    form = MyDynamicForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if len(form.some_tags.data) >= 1:
           # Do something with the received tags.
           pass

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

`index.html`

```
<input id="some_tags-0-tag_name"></input>
```

Each input id must use the following syntax: `"[some_tags]-[nth tag]-[tag_name]"`.  You should hopefully know best to create inputs and their ids taking into account the js frameworks you have available.

N.B. `tag_id = IntegerField(widget=HiddenInput(), default=0)` isn't necessary for receiving POSTed input but is useful if you store tags in a database and later want to populate the form with stored tags.

Comment: If `some_tags.data` is a list, `if form.some_tags.data` would be a more colloquial way to express the test in views.py.